# How does JDBC over LDAP connection work?

Tags: oracle, rails, ldap

The JDBC connection I should use is defined in Oracle SQL Developer with the following syntax:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://intranet.oid-01.dama.ch:3063/EDWHPD,cn=OracleContext,dc=emea,dc=dama,dc=ch
```

But with Ruby on Rails, I don't use JDBC. I use Ruby-oci8 gem.

I should probably get the server name or the SID from the LADP resource, but how can I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: OCI8 should support sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora settings, which would define LDAP sources for TNS lookups.

Comment: Did you try just the simple alias, i.e. `EDWHPD`